# SQL query to display data in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a grid view that displays data from a SQL Server database during page load. My gridview contains these columns:

```
AssetType, IssuedOn, ReturnedOn
```

I have used a query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM AssetRequest WHERE ReturnedOn IS NULL OR ReturnedOn ='' ORDER BY id DESC",
    conn);
```

which will display data from SQL Server in the gridview when `ReturnedOn` column doesn't have any data.

The new query has to satisfy these conditions,

1. It Should not displays a record when Assetype="Laptop" or "Desktop" and IssuedOn is not empty.
2. But if the Assetype="Laptop" or "Desktop" and IssuedOn is empty it should display the record.
3. If the Assetype=anything and Returnedon is not empty it should not display that record in gridview.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the SQL Query you posted doesn't do this: `which will display sql data in gridview when "AssetType" column has data, "IssuedOn" column has data and "ReturnedOn" column doesnt have any data.`. What's the filter you need to apply exactly?

Comment: I need a query which will display data when, AssetType <> "Laptop" or "Desktop" and IssuedOn = "any data" and ReturnedOn=null.

Comment: Just add these criteria to your sql query: ```SELECT * FROM AssetRequest WHERE (ReturnedOn IS NULL OR ReturnedOn ='') AND (IssuedOn IS NOT NULL) AND (AssetType NOT IN ('Laptop', 'Desktop')) ORDER BY id DESC```

Comment: @TWP, sorry i think i haven't made myself clear enough, the query has to satisfy these conditions, 1) It Should not displays a record when Assetype="Laptop" or "Desktop" and IssuedOn is not empty.  2) But if the Assetype="Laptop" or "Desktop" and IssuedOn is empty it should display the record. 3)If the  Assetype=anything and Returnedon is not empty it should not display that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this query resolves your issue.

```
SELECT *
FROM AssetRequest
WHERE (AssetType IN ('Laptop', 'Desktop') AND (IssuedOn IS NULL OR IssuedOn = '') AND (ReturnedOn IS NULL OR ReturnedOn = '')) 
OR (AssetType NOT IN ('Laptop', 'Desktop') AND (ReturnedOn IS NULL OR ReturnedOn = ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help

```
select * 
from AssetRequest 
where (ReturnedOn is null or ReturnedOn ='' )
and Assetype not in ('Laptop','Desktop')
union
select * 
from AssetRequest 
where Assetype in ('Laptop','Desktop') and IssuedOn is null or IssuedOn= ''
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code. But there is no data displayed in gridview, it returns empty

Comment: Does it display the records you wish when using this query in SSMS? Just to make sure the query is returning correct results

Comment: Put brackets around the OR-conditions in both union parts: ```(ReturnedOn is null or ReturnedOn ='')```

Comment: Now i am getting the error "The data type text cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable"

Comment: @santosh you are using TEXT datatype, instead use nvarchar(max)

Comment: @santosh UNION ALL will also give the answer without any error and you dont have to change the datatype

Comment: @TWP now the code is half working, but it fails to satisfy the condition 2 alone.

Comment: select * 
from AssetRequest 
where Assetype in ('Laptop','Desktop') and IssuedOn is null or IssuedOn= ''

this will satisfy your second condition

Answer (score 0):

According to your conditions above, this should meet your requirements:

```
select * 
from AssetRequest 
where 
  ((IssuedOn IS NULL OR IssuedOn = '') AND (Assetype IN ('Laptop', 'Desktop')) OR
  (ReturnedOn IS NULL OR ReturnedOn = '')
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't hide the record when Assettype and Issuedon column has data.